# How to detect Ctrl+S shortcut key in Angular?

Tags: angular, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to detect the Ctrl+S shortcut key in Angular. How many ways can you write it? In [this](https://netbasal.com/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-your-angular-app-9bf2e89862b3) article, the author mentioned that we can detect using three methods. But I can not figure out how to use any of those to detect the Ctrl+S event.

For me, the best case scenario is using `@HostListener` for the event, by listening on document Element. but I can't figure out the Ctrl+S event.

Answer (score 4):

check this:

```
 @HostListener('document:keydown.control.s', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('CTRL + S');
  }
```